# Reading tabular data from a line in bash

Tags: linux

I need to check if the pin that user gives exists and if exists then display their names and surnames... i need it in bash script  PS: we've got a file with  cardpins,name,surname,E/A (accepted or no for other questions) and account balance in this format:

```
0098876634569080 NIKOLAOU VASILEIOS Ε 25575 
0033872234566751 MAVRAGANIS GEORGIOS Α 12345
```

i've done this

```
read -p "Insert Pin"
if ! grep $REPLY filename
then
echo "ERROR"
exit 1
else grep $REPLY filename
$V1=grep -c $REPLY filename
head -$v1 filename | :   and then dunno :P
```

Comment: Why would you be doing this with a bash script?

Comment: BTW -- get in a habit of running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking about it here.

Comment: the exercise told...

Comment: ...that said, a question of the form "here are my requirements, here is code that implements half of them, please implement the rest" is generally speaking not a particularly good fit for StackOverflow. If you have a specific operation you want to know how to implement, show your best attempt at that operation, describe how it fails, and we'll help correct it -- but as it is, this is unclear and overbroad.

Comment: It would also be helpful to make your code descriptive of what you're trying to do; as a reader, it's hard to tell intent. For instance, what's the point of the `grep -c` call? How does knowing how many instances of the PIN exist help you implement your requirements?

Comment: but i dont know how to do the rest basically i want from one line to take specific info

Comment: it's n i don't know either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I gather it, this is essentially a question about reading fields from a file. `grep` isn't a good tool -- it would give you a match if the PIN were found in a different field (ie. balance), or if the value given were only a substring of a PIN (for instance, if the user entered `0` for their PIN). Consider instead:

```
read -p "Insert Pin"

found=0
while read -r pin name surname has_accepted balance; do
  # unlike grep, look ONLY in pin field, and ONLY for exact match
  if [[ $pin = "$REPLY" ]]; then
    found=1
    echo "Name is $name; surname is $surname; balance is $balance; etc"
    break # don't continue to look after we found a match
  fi
done <filename

if ! (( found )); then
  echo ERROR >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

See [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a long-form discussion of reading data in bash.

Comment: i need from the user only to give his pin and if it exist so i display him their name and surname  (from the other file )

Comment: Obviously, yes. The `read` here comes from the file, not the user, because it's inside the loop, and the entire loop's stdin is redirected with `<filename`.

Comment: i am new in this ... so plz relax ;))

Comment: if i need the pin only why in the loop i ve got the name surname too?

Comment: That's the list of fields to read **from the file**.

Comment: ah so in the loop put into variable the name , surname , pin etc right? and we use them later

Comment: There was a bug in the original, which would prevent the values from being correct after the loop exited -- was using `continue` rather than `break`. With that corrected, yes, you can use them after the loop is complete (or inside the `if`, as is already done). BTW, as an aside, this code will execute much faster against large input files with ksh93 [the version of ksh included with MacOS, for instance] than bash.

Comment: i ve got one question now says me this : if the answer is a check if the value tha the user give is multiple of 20 how i display the multiple of 20 ?

Comment: in c will be $REPLYmod20==0

Comment: `if (( ( REPLY % 20 ) == 0 )); then ...` -- btw, in general, putting unrelated questions in comments is unwelcome.

Comment: My answer was correct as-given; the `$` is not needed inside a math context.